# Does the "-S" in "pacman -S" stand for something? If so, what?

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

Many names of things on Linux are easy for me to remember if I know where they stem from (for example, `cd` standing for **c**hange **d**irectory).

The `-R` in `pacman -R package_name` obviously stands for "remove", but what does the `-S` stand for in `pacman -S package_name`? I guess it could be in**s**tall, but that doesn't explain the capitalization, and it's also a weird letter to choose, as opposted to `-I` or some such.

Answer (score 5):

It's short for "sync". From [pacman(8)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_operations):

> **-S, --sync**
>
> Synchronize packages. Packages are installed directly from the remote repositories, including all dependencies required to run the packages. [...]